# vlc broken after last update

Tags: updates, vlc

Ubuntu Unity 14.04 LTS 64bit.

I have been faithfully downloading and installing all updates. Last night everything was fine. I've downloaded two or three updates since then, and now when I try to run vlc I got errors. I then did apt-get remove vlc, apt-get autoremove, and finally sudo apt-get install vlc

This is what I get:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) but 2.1.5~ppa1 is to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) 
           but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1) 
           but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken package.
```

So NOW what can I do? :(

Comment: What is output of following command? `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`

Comment: You have a PPA causing trouble, remove it.